# Head voice and chest voice

Tags: voice, melody, hearing

When I hear something (a song for instance) I want to be able to tell whether I am hearing a head voice rendition or that of a chest voice.

Answer (score 1):

Not always easy, particularly in today's commercial music.  Singers strive to make them sound as similar as possible with no discernable break, and sometimes to 'mix' the two.

Also, how one singer 'places' a song may not be how YOU do.

Comment: The catch is I just need to know, a tip mayhap on how to distinguish between the two by "hearing" alone. For ear training as well as vocal chord training.